# improfile output length doesn't comply with input vectors length

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary

I have this code which draws a circle consisted of 50 points. I want to calculate the intensity of each point, so I used improfile.

```
THETA=linspace(0,2*pi,50);  
RHO=ones(1,50)*radius;
[X,Y] = pol2cart(THETA,RHO);
X=X+center(1);
Y=Y+center(2);

C = improfile(BW4,X,Y); % BW4 is a binary thinned image
```

I know that C must be a vector containing intensity of 50 points that I produced but when I write size(C) in work space I get this:

```
>> size(C)

ans =

142     1
```

I can't understand the problem with my code? any idea why it's working this way? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`improfile`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/improfile.html) will follow the path defined by the coordinates `X,Y` you provided but will not give you the results at these *exact* coordinates.

use the syntax *`C=improfile(I,xi,yi,n)`* with `n=50`. In your case:

```
C = improfile(BW4,X,Y,50);
```

This will force the output to be a [50x1] vector.